# Java, while loop with scanner inside and as a statement

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Trying to run the while loop for a password check. I do keep getting an error that the variable haslo cannot be found. Tried declaring it outside the loop - then it says, it's already declared. I know it can be done with infinite loop and the break command. Just curious whether it's possible this way.

```
String password = "pw123";

while (!haslo.equals(password)){

        System.out.println("Enter pw:");
        String haslo = reader.nextLine();

        if (haslo.equals(password))
            System.out.println("Right!");

        else
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
```

Comment: "Tried declaring it outside the loop" <- That was the right way. Declare it once, then just update the value inside the loop: `haslo = reader.nextLine();`

Comment: cos you are trying  to read the value of haslo before it is declared...

Comment: side bar: the loop must be executed at least once.  Consider changing to a do-while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Declare the variable haslo as `String haslo = "";` before the loop starts.
2. In the loop, replace your line `String haslo = reader.nextLine();` with `haslo = reader.nextLine();`.

**Reasoning**:

For 1 --> Your `while` loop is referencing the variable haslo before it is declared. So you need to declare it before it is referenced.

For 2 --> Once it is declared, you don't want to re-declare it because the one declared before the loop is already made available within the scope of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about scopes.

Your `haslo` variable is declared *inside* the while loop and so can only be used *inside* it, after he declaration. The condition of the while loop is evaluated before the declaration of `haslo` so you can't use `haslo` there.

To fix this, declare `haslo` outside the while loop:

```
String haslo = "";
while (!haslo.equals(password)){

    System.out.println("Enter pw:");
    haslo = reader.nextLine(); // <-- note that I did not write "String" here because that will declare *another* variable called haslo.

    if (haslo.equals(password))
        System.out.println("Right!");

    else
        System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this ? You need to declare haslo before the loop, then you can use it inside the loop, and avoid the infinite loop.

```
String password = "pw123";
String haslo = "";

while (!haslo.equals(password)){

    System.out.println("Enter pw:");
    haslo = reader.nextLine();

    if (haslo.equals(password))
        System.out.println("Right!");

    else
        System.out.println("Wrong!");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be found by following it step by step:

```
String password = "pw123"; (Good)

while (!haslo.equals(password)){ (Bad. What is Haslo? It is not defined before you use it here)
```

Try this:

```
String password = "pw123";
String haslo = "";
while (!haslo.equals(password)){
    System.out.println("Enter pw:");
    haslo = reader.nextLine();

    if (haslo.equals(password))
        System.out.println("Right!");

    else
        System.out.println("Wrong!");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare String INSIDE loop again! otherwise next time loop will not work! you gave it a reference, but loop needs to know what the reference is again.